# How to plot circular chromosomes with Gviz?

Tags: r, bioconductor, gviz

I am using Gviz to plot several tracks. I create a `GenomeAxisTrack()` and then several `AnnotationTrack()`s that I feed to `plotTracks()`. This produces a stacked output of tracks with annotated arrows as I want but the displays are linear. In some cases I have the complete genomes and I know they are circular (like some bacterial and viral chromosomes), how can I display the plots as circular?

I tried feeding to `AnnotationTrack()`; a `GRanges()` object with a `Seqinfo()` object specifying the `isCircular=TRUE` flag, but this didn't change the resulting plot.

Here is minimal code to create a linear plot, I would like one where the first and last arrow join up in a circle:

```
library(Gviz)
library(stringr)

track <- AnnotationTrack(start=c(1,5,7), end=c(2,6,10), strand=c('+','+','-'), stacking="dense", fill=c('red','blue', 'black'))
png(file=paste("test","png", sep="."))
plotTracks(track)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Note, I am not interested in alternative software recommendations, I would like to solve this with gviz if it is possible. Also asked this [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/112040/).

Comment: I would be amazed if there were a way to do that.

Comment: @DevonRyan why? i have use cases, but i'm not very familiar with gviz and its implementation

Comment: For track-based plots you would pretty much have to set it up for circular plotting from the very beginning in order for it to work. I'm aware that there are use-cases, but given where gviz was developed and the use-cases there it would be surprising if circular genomes were a consideration during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary author of Gviz confirmed to me via email that this is not possible:

> Gviz will only give you the traditional linear tracks. There are a
>   bunch of solutions available for visualizing circular genomes, most of
>   which are more interactive in nature and not implemented in the rather
>   static R graphics context. GGplot2 has some support for circular axes,
>   too. If you want to stay within the R environment I’d start there.
>   Ggbio is another option providing a somewhat higher-level interface.